# Is global.json supported in .netstandard2.0 projects?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard-2.0

There is a `global.json` file added in my .netstandard2.0 library. Do .netstandard2.0 libraries support `global.json` file?

Comment: Yes.  See Jan 13 answer at following : https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/781?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng the Jan 13th answer is about app configuration. `global.json`  is about SDK configuration.

Comment: Yes, global.json is basically about picking the SDK, and that happens before the project itself becomes relevant. (It's still find for an SDK-style project targeting .NET 3.5 for example...)

Comment: Did you  see : var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("config.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .Build();

Comment: For .NET applications e.g. .NET 6, I have seen global.json. Is global.json relevant to .netstandard2.0 projects?